# Mysql query for selecting equal buckets based on number of distinct entries given limit on total entries

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following requirement.

How do i select equal buckets(or nearly equal) buckets based on the ratio of total/ number of distinct entries.
Example: If the data in table is

```
10 u1 
11 u1
12 u2
13 u2
14 u2
15 u3
16 u3
17 u3
18 u3
19 u3
20 u4
21 u4
22 u4
23 u4
24 u4
25 u4
26 u4
27 u4
28 u4
29 u4
```

now there are 4 distinct values in second column and if i want to select 20 rows, the result should/,might look like

```
10 u1 
11 u1
12 u2
13 u2
14 u2
15 u3
16 u3
17 u3
18 u3
19 u3
20 u4
21 u4
22 u4
23 u4
24 u4
```

u1 and u2 dont have 5 (20/4) entries so return only available ones
can someone help?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberryadded example

Comment: If you want to select 20 rows, why are there only 15 in the result set?

Comment: @Strawberrybecause its not an equal split, but yea i can actually fill in data from other buckets if its not available. can you help?

Comment: Can I help? You tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an 'old school' solution...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,u INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(10,1),
(11,1),
(12,2),
(13,2),
(14,2),
(15,3),
(16,3),
(17,3),
(18,3),
(19,3),
(20,4),
(21,4),
(22,4),
(23,4),
(24,4),
(25,4),
(26,4),
(27,4),
(28,4),
(29,4);

SELECT id
     , u 
  FROM  
     ( SELECT x.*
            , COUNT(*) running 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.u = x.u 
          AND y.id <= x.id 
        GROUP 
           BY x.id 
        ORDER 
           BY running
            , u 
        LIMIT 15
     ) a
 ORDER 
    BY id;
+----+---+
| id | u |
+----+---+
| 10 | 1 |
| 11 | 1 |
| 12 | 2 |
| 13 | 2 |
| 14 | 2 |
| 15 | 3 |
| 16 | 3 |
| 17 | 3 |
| 18 | 3 |
| 19 | 3 |
| 20 | 4 |
| 21 | 4 |
| 22 | 4 |
| 23 | 4 |
| 24 | 4 |
+----+---+
```

Comment: How is this query working ? Looks elegant, but I am unable to find explanation for it. What happens if the data is skewed towards a particular "u" value. Let's say that out of 20 rows, u1 has 10, u2 has 5, u3 has 5. Now as per OP's problem definition, it should select (20/3 = 7) rows from each one of them..am I understanding the question right ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya It's not particularly elegant. Just run the subquery on its own - it *should* be fairly self-explanatory, but come back with any further questions.

Comment: understood! I see it as one more possible variation for emulating Row numbers within a Partition.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yes - but my solution doesn't scale very well.